# Where in ‘quibus vidēmus optābilīs mortēs fuisse’ is the act of choosing expressed?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, verbs, translation-explanation, dative, cicero

Towards the end of Cicero’s *Tusculan disputations* book 1, he says:

> Ita sunt multī, quibus vidēmus optābilīs mortēs fuisse cum glōriā.
>
> Cic. *Tusc.* 1.116

My translation of this is presently **‘So many are they for whom we see that there were desirable deaths with glory.’** The accusative with (perfect) infinitive could of course have been ‘to have been desirable deaths’, but I chose the more modern phrasing. Now, in two different translations they include some variant of choosing:

> so numerous are the men we see who set their hearts on death with glory.
>
> P. 47 of John Davie: *Cicero: On Life and Death*, Oxford UP, 2017.

> so numerous are those who made, as we see, the choice of death with honour.
>
> P. 141 of J. E. King: *Tusculan Disputations with an English translation by J. E. King*, Cicero XVIII, LCL 141, Harvard University Press, Cambridge, Massachusetts / London, England, first published 1927, revised 1945, ISBN 978-0-674-99156-9,  DOI: https://doi.org/10.4159/DLCL.marcus_tullius_cicero-tusculan_disputations.1927.

Am I missing something that these far more skilled translators see? Or is it simply that they are elaborating to create a better-flowing English sentence? Where in the quoted phrase is the act of choosing stated?

Comment: Translators can be highly skilled in the "massaging" of meanings; of standard dictionary definitions. These can be baffling; but, as with cryptic-crossword clues, a logic can be discerned. If something was "desirable" ("optabilis"); then, perhaps someone was inclined to choose it i.e. "they set their hearts on....", (Davie). Just a thought.

Comment: @tony Standard dictionary definitions are not the full truth, and ancient authors are certainly not bound by the dictionaries we modern people write. Sometimes a broader and deeper look will point to a very different result than a simple consultation of a dictionary. The interpretation by the translators is reasonable and doesn't require suspicious massaging. You're right to think of *optabilis*. See my answer below.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: I don't know why you have selected "suspicious": is a student-thwarting conspiracy  afoot?  Seriously, thinking "outside-the-box" is required. I recall perfect-subjunctive, "viderit", translated to "he should've had more sense"--which, at first glance, looked mental. Digging (thinking) this could be construed as, "he should have seen i.e. understood", "massaged" to the above. When the clues are cryptic the student must don his thinking-cap.

Comment: @tony I got the impression that you used the expression "massaging of meanings" in a very pejorative fashion, so I didn't find adding an additional "suspicious" to change the tone. My point was just that this translation task doesn't require supplying something that isn't there or any other suspicious steps. But it is true that this is tricky. And often there simply isn't a unique interpretation of what's being said. No conspiracies here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is the word *optabilis*.
The [entry in L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=optabilis&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) says it means "desirable" and similar things, but this is not the interpretation chosen by the translators.
To see where they are coming from, you have to dig deeper.

This adjective is derived from the verb [*optare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DO%3Aentry+group%3D26%3Aentry%3Dopto), which means not only "wish" but also "choose".
See the linked entry for details.
Derivatives are very productive in Latin, so it makes sense to read *optabilis* as not just being the typical meaning of the adjective as listed but as coming from any meaning of the underlying verb, although one must exercise such freedom with care.

One word to compare to is the sibling [*optatio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DO%3Aentry+group%3D26%3Aentry%3Doptatio) derived from the same verb.
L&S lists both meanings "wishing" and "choosing".

So, the translations you quote are reading *optabilis* as "choosable" rather than "desirable", and have reasonable grounds to do so.

Comment: The best part of this answer is the explanation of why and how they might have reached such a conclusion; it will serve me well in the future to consider this when I am doing more of my own translations.

Comment: @CannedMan That kind of generalizability was what I aimed at. I'm glad if it's helpful!